What is this movie about a girl who used a sperm donor to get pregnant but somebody switched the sperm with his own?
I have watched a Hollywood movie where the female lead wants to get pregnant by a sperm donor, but the male lead, a friend of hers, switches the sperm with his own.
As the story goes on the child grows and at his birthday party he tells the mother the truth and tells her that he loves her.
But the mother is engaged to marry another man and rejects him. But in the end she changes her mind and goes back to him.
The only thing I found through Google was The Backup Plan but that's not the one.

The Switch (2010)


The film stars Jennifer Aniston as Kassie, a 40-year-old single woman who decides to get pregnant using a handsome sperm donor. What she doesn’t know is that Wally, her neurotic best friend (and one-time boyfriend), played by Jason Bateman, has replaced the donor’s sample with his own during the drunken party to celebrate her insemination.
[Source]

The film is based on the short story "Baster" by Jeffrey Eugenides.
